# Changing favicon of Jekyll blog hosted on Github Pages?

Tags: html, jekyll

I used the jekyll's template Left by holman which had a favicon in the files but now I am unable to change it in my browser. I have replaced the favicon with mine but the change doesn't occur? I have also switched to a completely new template but its still there? My site is naumanahmad.me

Comment: I actually see the robot favicon, is that not right?

Answer (score 2):

Like Nitsan Baleli *(who commented on the question)*, I'm also seeing what looks like a cartoon version of Iron Man under http://naumanahmad.me/favicon.ico
*(the same image that's displayed in the top left corner of your site)*.

If you are seeing the old icon instead, it's probably in your local browser cache.
Try to delete your cache, or reload the page ignoring cached content *(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in most browsers)*, or load the page in a different browser where you never loaded it before, to make sure the browser loads the current content from your site instead of an old version from the cache.